# Console Input, losing UTF8 Encoding in NetBeans 9 with Maven

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, utf-8, java.util.scanner

Given the test sandbox, Using Netbeans9 (properly configured for UTF8 tasks), Java8.:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    String UTF8 = "UTF-8"; // Also tried UTF8, no way.
    System.setOut(new PrintStream(System.out, true, UTF8)); // Essential!
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in, UTF8);
    String command = "";
    while (!command.equals("quit")) {
        // command = scanner.nextLine(); // Doesn't work let's try something else.
        command = new String(scanner.nextLine().getBytes(UTF8), Charset.forName(UTF8));
        System.out.println("你好>" + command);
    }
}
```

The output result is:

```
hello!
你好>hello!
let's write some chinese: 再见！
你好>let's write some chinese: ��
```

The UTF8 is being output correctly by the System.out, but I keep losing the encoding from the Scanner. As you can see the scanner is well setup (afaik), and I tried both `UTF8` and `UTF-8`.

Which way may I mantain the original characters from the console?

**Update**
Seems like it is a Netbeans problem in combination with Maven.
As I said, Netbeans is properly setup, with `-J-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` and UTF-8 on the console configuration, but the keyboard input from the console loses the encoding. Only with a Maven Project.

Is is working properly from command line console and Eclipse.

Comment: On my machine, it is 你好 that's encoded incorrectly. It prints "雿�憟�>"

Comment: [1] I cannot reproduce your problem. Your code works fine for me using Win 10/JDK 8 with both NB 8.2 and NB 9.0. [2] What does `Charset.defaultCharset()` return for you? I get _"UTF-8"_.

Comment: Try this: [1] Change your loop to `while (true)`. [2] Completely remove the `String command...` variable from your code. [3] Directly output the text that is scanned within your call to `println()` like this: `System.out.println("你好>" + new String(scanner.nextLine().getBytes(UTF8), Charset.forName(UTF8)));` ... Do you still get the same result?

Comment: Yes, already tried that, thinking it was an assignment problem, it doesn't solve. It is definitely a Netbeans bug that prevents to input UTF8 characters from console. It works everywhere else.

`Product Version: Apache NetBeans IDE 9.0 (Build incubator-netbeans-release-334-on-20180708)
Java: 1.8.0_181; Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 25.181-b13`

Comment: [1] The only difference in our instances is that I have a strange message about NetBeans 8.2 from **Help > About** : `Apache NetBeans IDE 9.0 (Build incubator-netbeans-release-334-on-20180708)
Updates: NetBeans IDE is updated to version NetBeans 8.2 Patch 2
Java: 1.8.0_181; Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 25.181-b13
Runtime: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 1.8.0_181-b13`. But I think that 8.2 message is a minor bug since I also have 8.2 installed. [2] Anyway, try **Help > Check for Updates**, though I think you are already up to date. [3] What does  Charset.defaultCharset() return?

Answer (score 1):

This is **NOT** a solution, but since I can't reproduce your failure the listings below may help you resolve the problem yourself. Since this WORKSFORME, and we are using the same versions of NetBeans and JDK, I don't think the issue is NetBeans itself. Instead, we need to find the difference(s) in our configurations and settings.

One thing you could try is to delete your *Cache directory* and *User directory*. Their paths are shown at the bottom of the **Help > About** screen. However, be aware that doing that may remove your local Maven Repository and force it to be rebuilt. You may also lose some customized settings, so only do this if you know that you don't care about what may get removed.

The build output:

```
ant -f D:\\NB82\\ScanChinese -Dnb.internal.action.name=rebuild clean jar
init:
deps-clean:
Updating property file: D:\NB82\ScanChinese\build\built-clean.properties
Deleting directory D:\NB82\ScanChinese\build
clean:
init:
deps-jar:
Created dir: D:\NB82\ScanChinese\build
Updating property file: D:\NB82\ScanChinese\build\built-jar.properties
Created dir: D:\NB82\ScanChinese\build\classes
Created dir: D:\NB82\ScanChinese\build\empty
Created dir: D:\NB82\ScanChinese\build\generated-sources\ap-source-output
Compiling 1 source file to D:\NB82\ScanChinese\build\classes
compile:
Created dir: D:\NB82\ScanChinese\dist
Copying 1 file to D:\NB82\ScanChinese\build
Nothing to copy.
Building jar: D:\NB82\ScanChinese\dist\ScanChinese.jar
To run this application from the command line without Ant, try:
java -jar "D:\NB82\ScanChinese\dist\ScanChinese.jar"
deploy:
jar:
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)
```

The run output:

```
run:
hello!
你好>hello!
let's write some chinese: 再见！
你好>let's write some chinese: 再见！
BUILD STOPPED (total time: 41 seconds)
```

I used the NetBeans Project Wizard to create a simple Java application without Maven. I just did a copy/paste of your main() method:

```
package scanchinese;

import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ScanChinese {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        String UTF8 = "UTF-8"; // Also tried UTF8, no way.
        System.setOut(new PrintStream(System.out, true, UTF8)); // Essential!
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in, UTF8);
        String command = "";
        while (!command.equals("quit")) {
            // command = scanner.nextLine(); // Doesn't work let's try something else.
            command = new String(scanner.nextLine().getBytes(UTF8), Charset.forName(UTF8));
            System.out.println("你好>" + command);
        }
    }
}
```

netbeans.conf:

```
# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
# or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
# distributed with this work for additional information
# regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
# to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
# "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
# with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#   http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
# software distributed under the License is distributed on an
# "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
# KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
# specific language governing permissions and limitations
# under the License.
#
# Default locations of userdir and cachedir:
# (http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqWhatIsUserdir)
#
# On Windows ${DEFAULT_USERDIR_ROOT} will be replaced by the launcher
# with "<AppData>\NetBeans" where <AppData> is user's
# value of "AppData" key in Windows Registry under
# "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders"
# and ${DEFAULT_CACHEDIR_ROOT} will be replaced by the launcher
# with "<Local AppData>\NetBeans\Cache" where <Local AppData> is user's
# value of "Local AppData" key in Windows Registry under
# "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders"
#
# On Mac ${DEFAULT_USERDIR_ROOT} will be replaced by the launcher
# with "~/Library/Application Support/NetBeans" and
# ${DEFAULT_CACHEDIR_ROOT} with "~/Library/Caches/NetBeans"
#
# On other systems ${DEFAULT_USERDIR_ROOT} will be replaced by the launcher
# with "~/.netbeans" and ${DEFAULT_CACHEDIR_ROOT} with "~/.cache/netbeans"
#
# You can also use ${HOME} variable which will be replaced with
# user.home JVM system property value. This variable is valid only in
# netbeans_default_userdir and netbeans_default_cachedir properties.
#
# NOTE: If you specify a non-default userdir path on command line
# (--userdir option) and don't specify a cachedir path (--cachedir option),
# cachedir will be in "<userdir>/var/cache".
#
# Cachedir must be different from userdir. The same cachedir and userdir
# would cause problems.
#
netbeans_default_userdir="${DEFAULT_USERDIR_ROOT}/9.0"
netbeans_default_cachedir="${DEFAULT_CACHEDIR_ROOT}/9.0"

# Options used by NetBeans launcher by default:
# (can be overridden by explicit command line switches)
#
# Note that default -Xmx is selected for you automatically.
# You can find these values in var/log/messages.log file in your userdir.
# The automatically selected value can be overridden by specifying -J-Xmx
# here or on the command line.
#
# If you specify the heap size explicitly, you may also want to enable
# Concurrent Mark & Sweep garbage collector.
# (see http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqGCPauses)
#
netbeans_default_options="-J-XX:+UseStringDeduplication -J-Xss2m -J-Xms32m -J-Dnetbeans.logger.console=true -J-Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true -J-Dapple.awt.graphics.UseQuartz=true -J-Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true -J-Dsun.java2d.dpiaware=true -J-Dsun.zip.disableMemoryMapping=true -J-Dplugin.manager.check.updates=false -J-Dnetbeans.extbrowser.manual_chrome_plugin_install=yes -J--add-opens=java.base/java.net=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-opens=java.base/java.lang.ref=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-opens=java.base/java.security=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-opens=java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-opens=java.desktop/javax.swing.text=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-opens=java.desktop/javax.swing=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-opens=java.desktop/java.awt=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-opens=java.desktop/java.awt.event=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-opens=java.prefs/java.util.prefs=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-opens=jdk.jshell/jdk.jshell=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-modules=jdk.jshell -J--add-exports=java.desktop/sun.awt=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-exports=java.desktop/java.awt.peer=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-exports=java.desktop/com.sun.beans.editors=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-exports=java.desktop/sun.swing=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-exports=java.desktop/sun.awt.im=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-exports=jdk.internal.jvmstat/sun.jvmstat.monitor=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-exports=java.management/sun.management=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-exports=java.base/sun.reflect.annotation=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-exports=jdk.javadoc/com.sun.tools.javadoc.main=ALL-UNNAMED -J-XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions -J-Dswing.aatext=true -J-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=lcd -J-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8"

# Default location of JDK:
# (set by installer or commented out if launcher should decide)
#
# It can be overridden on command line by using --jdkhome <dir>
# Be careful when changing jdkhome.
# There are two NetBeans launchers for Windows (32-bit and 64-bit) and
# installer points to one of those in the NetBeans application shortcut 
# based on the Java version selected at installation time.
#
#netbeans_jdkhome="/path/to/jdk"
#netbeans_jdkhome="C:\Java\jdk-10.0.2"
#netbeans_jdkhome="C:\Java\jdk-11"
netbeans_jdkhome="C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_181"

# Additional module clusters:
# using ${path.separator} (';' on Windows or ':' on Unix):
#
#netbeans_extraclusters="/absolute/path/to/cluster1:/absolute/path/to/cluster2"
```

Help > About:

[image]

Comment: you got it, it is a combination of netbeans + maven problem. Unfortunately I can't link my main project from maven, so I'll now check a solution on how to compile with a different version of maven (if that can solve).

Comment: @donnadulcinea When I posted my answer I hadn't realized that your problem was specific to Maven, so I then tried using Maven 3.6.0 (the latest). Unfortunately I could not get it to work for the scanned Chinese characters either, so I'll be very interested to see if you find a solution. You might consider adding a **[maven]** tag to your question since this is definitely only an issue in NetBeans when using Maven.

Comment: Good suggestion. Did it. Still couldn't find any solution or workaround (except not using Netbeans with Maven).

Answer (score 0):

Too much code I think,

This works on a japanese system using eclipse

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String command = "";
while (!command.equals("quit")) {
    command = scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.println("你好>" + command);
}
```

**input/output**

```
wombat
你好>wombat
了解
你好>了解
```

Comment: Thank you, you're both right, it is a Netbeans issue. The output is correct both on Eclipse and Command prompt console.